# Blender renders same frame throughout animation

Tags: animation, soft-body

I am learning blender for a few weeks now. And I am trying to make a collision animation using soft body physics for my objects. I am able to see them in action in viewport without issues. But when I render them into an animation, either the animation renders the first frame throughout the entire video output or it gets stuck at some middle frame and from there I see the same frame to the end of the video.

But it also rendered just once using eevee fine. And after that not even in eevee it works.

If I reduce the objects from 20 to 5 or 6 it works fine. Animation renders. Having more objects creates the problem.

Attached the .blend file if someone wants to have a look at it. Please help.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/86igoi9a400xwe7/color_candy-animation_multi_jelly.blend/file

Comment: try installing blender again , never heard of that problem

Comment: @SHikhaMittal I have been using blender for over a month and I have rendered around 4-5 animations(120 frames total each) without issues. This is the first soft body animation though and I am experiencing this issue. Not sure if reinstalling will fix that.

Comment: It will not do any damage , Although i am using blender for 2 years but not on Mac  so , Still reinstalling clears a lot of problems

Comment: it looks like it's a bake problem, rebake and it seems to work fine

Comment: i think you should really try reinstalling because sometimes some files go corrupt

Comment: @moonboots How do I bake it? Can you give me the steps please?

Comment: Properties panel > Scene > Rigid Body World > Cache, then I guess Delete Bake, set the Simulation Start and End, and then Bake

Comment: @moonboots Just to clear. I found one more bake option in render properties. What does this do? Is this different from the bake in scene properties?

Comment: in Render, bake's purpose is to save the normals or diffuse of a material, it has nothing to do with baking a physic simulation. Did the rebake work?

Answer (score 0):

As moonboots indicated, baking animations is a possible answer. I just had this problem and running Bake command resolved it.